# match more than one arguement on a line

Tags: powershell, match

I read a file and I search some specific lines that contains the word "transfered" and the CODES "ZEN" and "ROK".
My script should select only the lines with these three parameters BUT the ROK should not be a star character `*`.

Here an example and the condition that I wrote:

lines:

```
Transfered    TWIST=1 ROK=TOTO      ZEN=C2813310

Transfered    TEST2=3 ROK=*         ZEN=C2813310

Transfered    CALIB=7 ROK=*         ZEN=C2813310

Transfered    LIKR1=9 ROK=TOTO      ZEN=C2813310
```

My if condition in order to match the elements:

```
$content = get-content "c:\test\log"    

foreach ($line in $content) {
    if ($line -match "Transfered.*ZEN=(.+?)\b.*")
```

My question is how to add to the same "if" condition the "ROK" parameters that it should not be equal to a `*` star.

So, at the end of the script, from the example above, I should have only these two lines where ROK is not equal to `*` :

```
Transfered    TWIST=1 ROK=TOTO      ZEN=C2813310

Transfered    LIKR1=9 ROK=TOTO      ZEN=C2813310
```

My script does also other tasks but these tasks are based no this filter that I have to apply.

Thank you in advance.

ps: I tried this one but didn't work:

```
if ($line -match "Transfered.*ZEN=(.+?).*ROK=(.+?)\b.*")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly this will be enough:

```
if ($line -match "Transfered.*ROK=[^\*].*ZEN")
```

Comment: I don't think that asterisk needs to be escaped. Within a character class it's going to be used as a literal match.

Comment: @mjolinor True,  but it does not hurt ;)

Comment: Hello,Thank you all for your replies. 

Saw, your solution works but only for this specific input that it is not what I need. But it works for this example.

CB: I didn't apply 100% your solution but you gave me the idea in what to modify so that my script works.

Here the modification:


if ($line -match "Transfered.*ROK=(^*)\b.*ZEN=(.+?)\b.*")

ps:I'm sorry, I'm still a powershell newbie...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$data = @'
I read a file and I search some specific lines that contains the word "transfered" and the CODES "ZEN" and "ROK". My script should select only the lines with these three parameters BUT the ROK should not be a star character "*".
Here an example and the condition that I wrote:
lines:
Transfered TWIST=1 ROK=TOTO ZEN=C2813310
Transfered TEST2=3 ROK=* ZEN=C2813310
Transfered CALIB=7 ROK=* ZEN=C2813310
Transfered LIKR1=9 ROK=TOTO ZEN=C2813310
My if condition in order to match the elements:
'@.split("`n")

$data | ? { $_ -match 'Transfered.*ROK=[^*]+ZEN.*' } | % {$_}
```

Comment: the last part `| % {$_}` is totally useless.